# Percentage width for a relative layout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have a layout that I'd like to take up only a percentage of the screen's width (image on the left).  Right now, my relative layout is spanning the entire width of the display (image on the right).  How can I fix it to have margins on the left and right?

[image]

This is how I've defined my relative layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp">
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

for this `you can use LinearLayout with weightSum and layout_wright property`

**so try following code**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="8" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <!-- 1/8 % of Screen to left of your RelativeLayour -->
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <!-- 1/8 % of Screen to right of your RelativeLayour -->

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this worked for me except that I had to change the layout_width of the linear layouts to an actual value (I set mine to 20dp instead of 0dp).  thanks!

Comment: scientiffic - you shouldn't have to put any values for `layout_width` at all. The reason it didn't work for you was because the relative_layout had wrap_content specified

Answer (score 1):

Use new percentage support library.

```
compile 'com.android.support:percent:24.0.0'
```

Using PercentageRelativelayout you can done this. See below example.

```
    <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_marginLeftPercent="5%"
    app:layout_marginRightPercent="5%"
    app:layout_marginTopPercent="5%"
    app:layout_marginBottomPercent="5%"
    >
</RelativeLayout>
```

For more Info [Android Doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html)

*For Example & Tutorial * [Tutorial1](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/know-percent-support-library/en) [Tutorial2](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/percentrelativelayout-in-android/) [Tutorial3](http://www.androidauthority.com/using-the-android-percent-support-library-630715/)

Comment: does TextInputLayout work inside PercentRelativeLayout..?

Comment: @Vishal yes TextInputLayout work inside PercentRelativeLayout. Its work for me.

Comment: For those who stumble on this like I have, this library is deprecated and as was the case for me, just not work. From what I have recently understood, percentages really have no reliable support outside of Constraint Layouts. Linear layout will work in some situations, but can be problamatic in many others. Unfortunately, constraint layouts have their owrn issues, so prepare to do a lot of nexting if you want to go the perentage route.